# Why skb_transport_header does not calculate correctly?

Tags: c++, c, linux-kernel, netfilter

I write an application with `netfilter hooks`.

It seems `skb_transport_header` function does not calculate correctly (sometimes but not always):

```
struct tcphdr* tcp_header = NULL;
tcp_header = (struct tcphdr*)skb_transport_header(skb); // somtimes incorrect address.
tcp_header = (struct tcphdr*)((char*)ip_header + (ip_header->ihl * 4));// always correct address.
```

Where is my wrong?

Comment: What hook do you use? Can you check for the TCP type before operation?

Comment: @IlyaMatveychikov: Yes, I check the TCP protocol.

Comment: I'll suggest you to clarify the problem by performing a packet analisys in case when theese methods gives you different results. In other words you'll need to dump whole the packet if `(struct tcphdr*)skb_transport_header(skb)` != `(struct tcphdr*)((char*)ip_header + (ip_header->ihl * 4))`

Answer (score 4):

You can check it in here:
http://www.roman10.net/how-to-filter-network-packets-using-netfilterpart-2-implement-the-hook-function/
The problem is netfilter implement in network layer, when packet go up from physical layer, you catch packet before it reaching tcp layer, some function isn't process.

Comment: thanks for this.. I was running around for about 2 hours trying to figure out why my incoming data wasn't right!

Answer (score 0):

Kernel version is very importnt information.In Linux network kernel, transport_header(and many other properties) of SKB are not set when it first created (by the driver), the SKB is processed  layer by layer while SKB's data pointer is moved. So if your hook is lower, aka in BRIDGE level, it may haven't been set when you access it.